# How can React Native Expo application on Android receive OneSignal Background/Data notification?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

This is my backend code

```
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "XXX",
        'include_player_ids' => $player_id_arr,
        'data' => array("type" => $type, "data" => $data),
        'content_available' => true,
        'ios_sound' => $notification,
        'priority' => 10,
    );

    if (isset($message)) {
        $fields['contents'] = array("en" => $message);
    }

    $fields = json_encode($fields);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    ...
```

Everything is simple: when `$message` variable is NOT empty it send usual push notification and when `$message` is empty, it send background/data notification.
On React Native side I use

```
OneSignal.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(notificationReceivedEvent => {
    console.log("notification: ", notificationReceivedEvent);
    notificationReceivedEvent.complete(notification);
});
```

to receive notification. This works fine for iOS(usual push notification and background/data notification) and for Android(usual push notification) but it doesn't work for Android(background/data notification).

According to the https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/service-extensions#android-notification-extender-service I have created `android/app/src/main/java/com/example/NotificationServiceExtension.java` file with the following content:

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.onesignal.OSNotification;
import com.onesignal.OSMutableNotification;
import com.onesignal.OSNotificationReceivedEvent;
import com.onesignal.OneSignal.OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler;
import android.text.Spannable;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.graphics.Color;
import java.math.BigInteger;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class NotificationServiceExtension implements OSRemoteNotificationReceivedHandler {

    @Override
    public void remoteNotificationReceived(Context context, OSNotificationReceivedEvent notificationReceivedEvent) {
        OSNotification notification = notificationReceivedEvent.getNotification();

        // Example of modifying the notification's accent color
        OSMutableNotification mutableNotification = notification.mutableCopy();
        mutableNotification.setExtender(builder -> {
            // Sets the accent color to Green on Android 5+ devices.
            // Accent color controls icon and action buttons on Android 5+. Accent color does not change app title on Android 10+
            builder.setColor(new BigInteger("FF00FF00", 16).intValue());
            // Sets the notification Title to Red
            Spannable spannableTitle = new SpannableString(notification.getTitle());
            spannableTitle.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),0,notification.getTitle().length(),0);
            builder.setContentTitle(spannableTitle);
            // Sets the notification Body to Blue
            Spannable spannableBody = new SpannableString(notification.getBody());
            spannableBody.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),0,notification.getBody().length(),0);
            builder.setContentText(spannableBody);
            //Force remove push from Notification Center after 30 seconds
            builder.setTimeoutAfter(30000);
            return builder;
        });
        JSONObject data = notification.getAdditionalData();
        Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Received Notification Data: " + data);

        // If complete isn't call within a time period of 25 seconds, OneSignal internal logic will show the original notification
        // To omit displaying a notification, pass `null` to complete()
        notificationReceivedEvent.complete(mutableNotification);
    }
}
```

and add `<meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationServiceExtension" android:value="com.example.NotificationServiceExtension" />` to the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
  <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationServiceExtension" android:value="com.example.NotificationServiceExtension" />
...
```

But I still can't receive background/data notification on Android.